# ¿Cómo mostrar por consola un objeto junto con sus parámetros?

Tags: c#, .net

No he dado con la solución al imprimir lo que tiene el siguiente objeto juntos con sus parámetros por consola. He intentado usando `WriteLine` del objeto, pero no funciona.

Este es el código que tengo, lo coloco como ejemplo:

```
Random nro_credito = new Random();
monto = 500000;
int nro = nro_credito.Next(10000000, 99999999);
Hipotecario hipotecario = new Hipotecario(nro, monto);
Console.WriteLine(hipotecario);
```

En ese ejemplo, ¿cómo puedo imprimir el objeto `hipotecario` junto con sus parámetros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice @FernandoCarraro puedes sobrescribir el método `ToString()`. Sin embargo, también puedes incluir el paquete nuget de [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) y hacer simplemente:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...    
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hipotecario));
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Aclarar que esto solo funciona por que el Objeto en cuestión de tipo Hipotecario cumple con el formato JSON de lo contrario otros formatos de objetos reventaría.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el método `ToString()` de C#, que es similar al método `toString()` de Java. Este método es útil para imprimir los datos que deseas mostrar con `Console.WriteLine()`

**Ejemplo.** Mostrar Dato1 y Dato2.

```
public override string ToString(){
                return "Clase{Dato 1:"+this.Dato1+", Dato2: "+this.Dato2+"}";
            }
```

Usamos el modificador `override` para modificar el comportamiento de `ToString()`. Con esto puedes imprimir los datos que deseas:

```
Console.WriteLine(miClase);
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
using System;
                    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Random nro_credito = new Random();
            long monto = 500000;
            int nro = nro_credito.Next(10000000, 99999999);
            Hipotecario hipotecario = new Hipotecario(nro, monto);
            Console.WriteLine(hipotecario.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    class Hipotecario{
        private long monto;
        private int nmro;
        
        public Hipotecario(int nmro, long monto){
            this.Nmro=nmro;
            this.Monto = monto;
        }
        
        public int Nmro{
                get;
                set;
        }
        
        public long Monto{
                get;
                set;
        }
        
        
        public override string ToString(){
            return "Hipotecario{Nmro:"+this.Nmro+", Monto: "+this.Monto+"}";
        }
    }
```

Salida:

```
Hipotecario{Nmro:10894340, Monto: 500000}
```

Espero haber ayudado.